# Unable to update RPi 4 after installing Plex

Tags: pi-4, apt, update

I'm unsure as to what happened, but I am unable to run `sudo apt update` on my rpi 4. I believe this problem came into play after I installed plex via [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-plex-server/) tutorial. I have looked in `/etc/resolv.conf` and it shows that my only nameserver is 127.0.0.1, but I have read this is normal after installing PiHole (which I have as well). The output of `ping google.com` is as follows, and from what I can make of it (which may not be much), it looks okay. I'm unsure what to do from here

```
64 bytes from den16s03-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.2.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=30.1 ms
```

Comment: `I am unable to run sudo apt update` What do you mean by that? Do you get error messages? If you do then add this information to your question. Please post *full* messages.

Comment: Hello and welcome – Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. – Please think as other users here, it's even hard to guess what happened and what you should do.

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/108249/edit) your question and add the output of this commands to it: `ping -c3 raspbian.raspberrypi.org` and `curl http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ | grep '<title>'`